# enlarge Excel dialog box for screen capture

Tags: excel, zooming, screenshot

I have to make a high resolution screen capture of part of an Excel session. I can zoom in on the contents of the spreadsheet, but the Sort dialog box I want to capture as well doesn't change size, so its pixel resolution doesn't increase.

Working on Windows 7, Excel Professional Plus 2010, screen 1280x1024 (max).

Comment: Look toward right-click blank area of desktop, Screen resolution, Make text and other items larger or smaller, Larger - 150%. May require a reboot so be prepared to shut everything down.

Comment: @Jeeped Screen resolution is already at its maximum.

Comment: Then look toward the Windows 7 Magnifier utility. Hint: do not use Alt+PrntScrn to get your screen capture as it seems to collect a .BMP with less quality than a screen capture program's (e.g. Snipping Tool) .PNG capture.

Comment: @Jeeped I just found the magnifier myself, googling <vision impaired Excel user>. That with snipping tool should do the trick. Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First look toward right-click blank area of desktop ► Screen resolution ► Make text and other items larger or smaller ► Larger - 150%. May require a reboot so be prepared to shut everything down.

If that is insufficient, next look toward the Windows 7 Magnifier utility. Hint: do not use Alt+PrntScrn to get your screen capture as it seems to collect a .BMP with less quality than a screen capture program's (e.g. Snipping Tool) .PNG capture.

Answer (score 0):

When I went to turn on the magnifier I found a solution that works better for me than the magnifier. Under Control Panel -> Ease of Access -> Optimize Visual Display -> Change the size of text and icons I selected Larger - 150% and logged out and in. There's a little pixelation but it does what I need.

FWIW I don't understand the downvote to the question. Someone might think this is something I should have known.